# Пример триггера Mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

Кто может привести пример триггера, когда в при `UPDATE` таблицы `table1`, информация обновленной записи добавляется в таблицу `table2`.
Вопрос в синтаксисе и построении запроса

```
DELIMITER $$

    CREATE TRIGGER update
    BEFORE UPDATE ON log
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN

    INSERT INTO recordlog Set from = NEW.IdtoUserRecordstouser, to = NEW.IdUserRecordstouser, status = 0, id_record = NEW.IdRecordstouser;

    END;
    $$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Документация не помогла? Уточните, пожалуйста, что именно не ясно.

Comment: Все ясно, но почему-то триггер не создается. Обновил вопрос

Comment: В этом была проблема. Отредактировал вопрос, добавив подвопрос

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk будьте добры, отметьте вопрос как верный, дабы соблюсти порядок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы используете ключевое слово `update` в имени триггера.